# Fetch username/password properties from external secrets.txt to DB2 data source in app.yaml : spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, yaml, microservices, spring-webflux

Fetch username/password properties from external secrets.txt to DB2 data source in app.yaml : spring boot

Java File:

```
    @PropertySource(factory = YamlPropertySourceFactory.class, value = "${secrets.filepath}")
    public class XyzApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
        @Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
        private String username;
    
        @Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
        private String password;
```

App.yml:

```
      secrets:
       filepath: file:src/main/resources/secrets/secret.txt
    
      ​Spring:
         datasource:
            url: jdbc:some db conn path
            username: username (??)
            password: password (??)
```

Secrets.txt

```
    spring.datasource.username: abcd
    spring.datasource.password: p@ssWord
```

but username, password not picking from secret.txt to app.yml

Kindly suggest any corrections or alternative

Comment: if you want your secrets in a txt file then you have to read and parse the txt file manually.

Answer (score 0):

Just Remove , usrnme/passwrd from spring.datasource section in app.yaml : Run your app - Yes miracle will happen :)

```
​Spring:
         datasource:
            url: jdbc:some db conn path
            username: username (remove this)
            password: password (remove this)
```